# Replacing numbers in a list whilst retaining letters in R

Tags: r, xml, for-loop

I am trying to reorganize some data in an XML-file, where I remove every other node in a list, i.e.

```
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts1" TIME_VALUE="0"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts2" TIME_VALUE="2900"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts3" TIME_VALUE="2900"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts4" TIME_VALUE="4440"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts5" TIME_VALUE="4440"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts6" TIME_VALUE="7870"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts7" TIME_VALUE="7870"/>
etc...
```

becomes

```
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts2" TIME_VALUE="2900"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts4" TIME_VALUE="4440"/>
        <TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts6" TIME_VALUE="7870"/>
etc...
```

I have removed every other line in the XML using the following code, which results in the data above:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("SCRIPTTEST.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
time_xml <- getNodeSet(doc,"//*/TIME_SLOT")
ts_correct <- time_xml[seq(0, length(time_xml), 2)]
```

I have kept the data as an XML because the resulting list must later be integrated into another XML file.

Now, I want to rename each entry so it is a regular list, i.e. "ts1", "ts2", "ts3", etc.
I think a for-loop with some RegEx would be able to do this, but I am having trouble coming up with a way to make sure both the numbering is correct and the "ts" is preserved. I would preferably have it so I can run the script on multiple files, but that is a secondary concern.

Any help in figuring this out would be most appreciated, note that I am a beginner at virtually all things programming!

Best,
Clemens

Answer (score 0):

#EDIT:

step1) convert your data into a vector (each item will be "<TIME_SLOT...>")

step2) gsub (here used within mapply)

step3) convert this back into XML

```
#my example vector: (this is not step1)
df <- c('<TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts2" TIME_VALUE="2900"/>',
        '<TIME_SLOT TIME_SLOT_ID="ts4" TIME_VALUE="4440"/>')

#step2
cnt <- seq(df) #this is just a vector numbering from 1 to x
df1 <- mapply(function(x,y) {gsub('ID="ts." TIME', paste0('ID="ts',y,'" TIME'), x)}, x=df, y=cnt)
df1 <- as.vector(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! When I run this, nothing seems to happen. If it wasn't clear before, I want "ts2" to become "ts1", "ts4" to become "ts2", etc. with everything else staying as is.

Comment: mh..if I get you right, then you just need to add a column that consists of "ts" followed by increasing numbers. You can just do `cbind( df, paste0("ts", seq(nrow(df)) )`

Comment: Trying these two doesn't seem to change anything in my data. I have not converted the XML nodeset to a dataframe, should I be doing this? To reiterate I want the formatting to remain exactly as is but I want a script that goes through every TIME_SLOT_ID = "tsX" and make sure it is ascending 1,2,3, etc.

Comment: no, no data.frame. Like I said, you need to convert this to a list or vector first. I didn't get that you wanted to replace the number and leave the rest as it is. I edited my answer.